# SVG placeholders

Tags: svg

I would like to make an area inside an SVG that makes it easy to add other elements or paths to the SVG.

If I use the `<div id="name123"></div>`, the inner SVG path or element doesn't render.

If I use the group tag `<g id="name123"></g>` it will render.

But I am wondering what other tags or implementations or ? could be used as placeholders in SVGs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. < defs > region in SVG
2. XML entities.
   You may define them in the document header:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd" [
<!ENTITY X"#E3EFD3">
<!ENTITY Y"#22969E">
]>
```

and you use them as you know it from HTML entities with "&":

```
<stop  offset="0.5" stop-color="&X;"/>
```

Comment: If you put things in <defs> they don't directly render. They may of course do so indirectly in many different ways e.g. as paint servers or markers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're asking [what elements are containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermContainerElement)?